# UIViewcontroller won't show (storyboard deleted)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I accidentaly deleted the main UIViewcontroller in my sotryboard. I tried dragging a new one in my storyboard but when i launch the app nothing shows up except a black screen.

I know hat I'm supposed to set the entry point or something like that but I can't remember how to do that as long as I didn't code for ages...

Thanks for your help and have a nice day ! :)

Comment: Just check the "is initial view controller" box in the attributes inspector.

Comment: Honestly Matt, you didn't have to be that rude. People sometimes forget things. Having forgot this detail doesn't mean that I don't know iOS programming. I already have a few apps online but as I told, I just didn't dev for the last few years. The next time, please think before speaking (or biting). Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your view controller and click on the Attributes inspector in the left pane.
[image]

Then check this box.
[image]